# why js uglfier mangle cause the issue when using AngularJS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rail 4 with latest AngularJS framework, I found when I use uglifier with mangle=false, everything is fine. But if I use uglifier with mangle=true, then I received the error like

```
Failed to instantiate module *** due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: e
```

Comment: Plz refer https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#a-note-on-minification for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use 'Dependency Annotation' because all your services/controllers/directives are renamed and thus no longer working.
See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

There are different ways to get around this. E.g. you could use the $inject property like this:

```
var MyController = function($scope, greeter) {
   // ...
}
MyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'greeter'];
someModule.controller('MyController', MyController);
```

There is also a nice node plugin https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate that you can use in your build pipeline to automate the whole annotation stuff...